# Derivative of expresion with matrix in exponent

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation, matrix-equations

I am looking at a proof which states the following results:

$$\frac d {dt}\left(A \frac{t^2}{2!} \right)=A^2t$$

where $A$ is a matrix.

Why is it that the matrix gets squared, and for the derivative of $At^3$, get cubed? etc

Thanks

Comment: Why do you write "Where $A$ is a matrix" with a capital "W", as if it were the beginning of a new sentence? $\qquad$

Comment: Some more context is needed here. The result need not be true when $A$ is a constant matrix.